# Passing bool in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I have a framework written in Obj-C that I have to amend and I am having great difficulty trying to have an Obj-C function take a boolean. I am a Swift developer.

How can I do this in Obj C?

```
- (void)loginWithSamlToken:(Boolean *)saml credentialToken:(NSString *)credentialToken completionHandler:(METLogInCompletionHandler)completionHandler {
    [self loginWithMethodName:@"login" parameters:@[@{@"saml": saml}, @{@"credentialToken": credentialToken}] completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

I get error on the second line

> {@"saml": **saml**}": Collection element of type 'Boolean *' (aka
> 'unsigned char *') is not an Objective-C object

How can I pass a Bool in Obj-C?  Any help would be very much appreiated

Any help with this conversion would be very much appreaciated ! thank you

Comment: remove the * after boolean. * is for only objects and Boolean is not an object type.

Comment: @teja-nandamuri Yes tried that, did not help

Comment: you need to pass the boolean to an nsnumber object, and store the nsnumber object in place of saml . You can't have bool values in a dictionary. You can only have objects.

Comment: @teja-nandamuri I have never written any ObjC.  Would you be able to help and show how that is done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass the boolean to an nsnumber object, and store the nsnumber object in place of saml . You can't have bool values in a dictionary. You can only have objects.

Try this:

```
- (void)loginWithSamlToken:(BOOL)saml credentialToken:(NSString *)credentialToken completionHandler:(METLogInCompletionHandler)completionHandler {

    NSNumber *boolNumber = [NSNumber numberWithBool:saml];
    [self loginWithMethodName:@"login" parameters:@[@{@"saml": boolNumber}, @{@"credentialToken": credentialToken}] completionHandler:completionHandler];
}
```

Also you could simply surround the saml in @() which makes it an `NSNumber` object.So this `{@"saml": saml}` would become `{@"saml": @(saml)}`
-Credits to @rmaddy

Comment: There's a much simpler way: `@{@"saml" : @(saml)}`. Just wrap the `BOOL` value with `@( )`. This creates the corresponding `NSNumber` object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment maddy. I will add it in my answer.